# PHP Regex match either or on one word without using brackets?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

My current pattern is this:

```
pattern=("/(.*)(\bIf you want\b)(.*)/iu");
```

But with:

```
preg_replace($pattern, '$1*$2*$3', $result);
```

So the three parts must be replaced as they are by the $1, $2 and $3 but I want to allow some further flexibility so I can detect for example both these lines:

```
If you want
If I want
```

So I could simply do this:

```
pattern=("/(.*)(\bIf (I|you) want\b)(.*)/iu");
```

but it creates a problem since I need to replace $1, $2 and $3. The patterns are inserted dynamically and thus are all different:

```
$pattern = "/(.*)(\b".$value."\b)(.*)/iu";
```

The $value sometimes has a modifier like in the example above "if (you|I) want" but other patterns may be simply "what happened next" with no modifier. So the extra brackets cause an issue but I can't find another way to do it.

EDIT: Please note the issue here is with the $1, $2 and $3 preg_replace. With a pattern like

```
"/(.*)(\bwhat happened next\b)(.*)/iu"
```

this goes through fine, but with an additional bracket like with

```
"/(.*)(\bIf (I|you) want\b)(.*)/iu"
```

it won't replace properly with the $1, $2 and $3 preg_replace.

Also I realise it can be done like this

```
 If you want|If I want
```

But its not particularly eloquent!

Comment: Do you mean `$value` can contain  user defined pattern? Can't you use non-capturing groups - `"/(.*)(\bIf (?:I|you) want\b)(.*)/iu"`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The issue comes in the preg_replace where it replaces the three bracketed queries with $1,$2 and $3. If you add another bracket *sometimes* then it obviously won't work properly. That's why I need to do this potentially without brackets...or there must be some other way.

Comment: You want to get a substring from the start of the string up to the match, then the match, and then the text after the match? Do you expect a single match in a string?

Comment: He meant you should put **?:** inside of brackets in **$value** to make non-capturing bracket groups. In other words your var should contains something like this `$value = "If (?:I|you) want";`

Comment: Use named capturing groups and `preg_replace_callback`. See http://ideone.com/4gTHQA

Comment: Ok I see - non capturing brackets, I wasn't aware of them. Yes that works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you cannot rely on the *numbered* capturing groups as their number may vary since the user-defined pattern part may include an arbitrary number of numbered capturing groups.

A way out can be via using *named* capturing groups. The only trouble with them is that PHP does not support named backreferences in the replacement pattern. It can be worked around using the `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$s = 'text If you want this';
echo preg_replace_callback("/(?<start>.*)(?<mid>If (I|you) want)(?<end>.*)/siu", function($m) {
    return $m['start'].'*'.$m['mid'].'*'.$m['end'];
}, $s);
// => text *If you want* this
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/qmBdOO).

You may "obfuscate" group names so that they could not conflict with the user-defined patterns. Or let users know what names cannot be used inside the pattern.

Note `s` modifier will make `.` match line breaks as well.

The above solution will match the *last* occurrence of `mid` group as the first `start` pattern is a greedy dot pattern. If your string contains multiple matches and you want to make the `mid` group match the first occurrence in the string, replace `(?<start>.*)` with `(?<start>.*?)`. Else, you need to decide what the algorithm should be like.

Answer (score -1):

For just matching I or you, this worked for me:

```
$pattern=("/(.*)(\bIf (?:i|you) want\b)(.*)/iu");
```

Comment: I think people are just answering too quickly. The whole point of my question is WITHOUT brackets. Not sure if it can be done or not but I already listed your solution here, in my question....I obviously know how to do this but adding extra brackets is what causes the problem in the first place.

Comment: But this isn't the normal bracket.notice the user of  ` ?: i`. This makes this bracket `non-capturing bracket groups`

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
pattern=("/(.*)(\bIf [I|you]+ want\b)(.*)/iu");
```

Comment: I already tried that but square brackets don't work like that. Try it, it doesn't work: regex101.com

Comment: Sorry see updated answer. Works on http://regexr.com. I missed the `+`.

Comment: @DrRoach It seems like you don't understand the difference between [] and ()

Comment: [] - Character match. () - Capture group.

Comment: @DrRoach With your **[I|you]+** something like this **"If yoII want"** will be matched too.

Comment: `[]` is a character **class**, not match. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html